# i am try to make jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-ui

this code is not work

**error:** function not defind

```
!function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function () {
    var hello= {};
    hello.msg=function(){
        alert('hiii')
    }
})
```

but  i am write a code without use this ,then it's work.

```
!function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function () {
    /* write your function*/
})
```

now, you can help me. how to make proper jquery plugin!!!

Comment: Where did you see this plugin structure?  What do you want the plugin to do?  Which line has the error?  How are you calling the plugin?

Comment: For a jQuery plugin to work, you need to define a function on either `$` or `$.fn`.  See: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: I see this link but i want to make plugin like NGprogressbar. And it's define var Ngprogress ={} ; as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;(function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        root.plugin_name = factory();
    }
})(this, function() {
    var plugin_name = {};    
    plugin_name.status = null;
    plugin_name.start = function() {
        alert('done');
        return this;
    };
    return plugin_name;
});
```

plugin_name is define your plugin name.
and root.enter-plugin-name is required.

Answer (score -1):

`hello` array initialization is wrong. It shoule be `var hello = [];`

Comment: `hello` is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: i make plugin like ngprogressbar.  http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/nprogress.js   , your can see in  js file. it's   define var NProgress = {}; as a function.